# Whitespace of unknown nature occured. Fixed-height

Tags: html, css

I decided to start some hand-coding rather than using frameworks. Even though it seemed to be quite fine, now I collided with a problem of whitespace of uknown origin to me.

Got also a test **[site](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/full/wrxoz/)** where you can inspect elements.

**The Problem**

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0RBn.png) of the problem.
The space between the blue area marked by Dev Tools and "Our Portfolio" slogan.

In the template PSD file the Section 1 occupies 568 pixels, so, assuming I want a pixel-perfect style, I set the 568px height to the `.section-1` element

```
.section-1{
    height: 568px;
}
```

And even though the Dev Tools tell that it's height is really 568 pixels, the section is followed and preceeded by some kind of whitespace of utterly unknown nature.

I don't wanna be using workaround like

```
.section-1{
   margin-bottom: -140px;
}
```

but would like to know what's so wrong about my markup and styles that produce this whitespace.

**Update**

The issue is with the collapsing margins and also with the Chrome's and Other's Browsers' default styles.

Comment: A `margin-top: 118px` on .section-header is causing the issue http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fell in a trap called [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). It's a well defined, but rather unknown behaviour. If you know about it, it can be very useful.

The `margin-top` from your `.section-header` spills over. If you change that margin to a padding and add `margin-top: 0;` , the additional whitespace will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

A `margin-top: 118px` on `.section-header` is causing the issue

Hard to explain but you can read more on collapsing margins here  http://sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins